# Running a batch process with arguments

Tags: java, xml, arguments, spring-batch, batch-processing

Hi i'm trying to run a batch process in Java with Spring batch, i need pass the batchContext.xml like argument to my main, but i don't know how do it, this is my launcher:

```
public final class Launcher {

private static final String LOG_DECORATOR = "****************************************.";
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger("batch");
private static final Long MIL = 1000L;

private Launcher(){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    LOG.info(LOG_DECORATOR);
    LOG.info(" INICIO DEL PROCESO ");
    LOG.info(LOG_DECORATOR);

    LOG.info("Cargando datos de configuracion");

    for(Object object: args){
        System.out.println(object);
    }       

    final ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(args[0]);

    final PropertyFacade property = applicationContext.getBean(PropertyFacade.class);
    Assert.notNull(property, "Datos de configuracion no cargados correctamente");
    final String entorno = property.property("entorno");
    LOG.info("Entorno: ".concat(entorno));
    System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", property.property("tempFiles"));
    final JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) applicationContext.getBean("jobLauncher");
    final Job job = (Job) applicationContext.getBean("job");
    long tiempoComenzar;
    long tiempoTerminar;
    tiempoComenzar = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        final JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
        LOG.info("Job Status : " + execution.getStatus());
        LOG.info("Job completed");
    } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
        LOG.info("Error Launcher: ".concat(e.toString()));
        LOG.error("Exception Launcher",e);
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        LOG.info("Error Launcher: ".concat(e.toString()));
        LOG.error("Exception Launcher",e);
    } catch(JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException e){
        LOG.info("Error Launcher: ".concat(e.toString()));
        LOG.error("Exception Launcher",e);
    } catch(JobParametersInvalidException e){
        LOG.info("Error Launcher: ".concat(e.toString()));
        LOG.error("Exception Launcher",e);
    } catch(JobRestartException e){
        LOG.info("Error Launcher: ".concat(e.toString()));
        LOG.error("Exception Launcher",e);
    }finally {
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext).close();
        tiempoTerminar = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long tiempoDedicado = (tiempoTerminar - tiempoComenzar) / MIL;
        LOG.info(
                "Fin. Tiempo dedicado a la consulta: ".concat(String.valueOf(tiempoDedicado)).concat(" segundos."));
        LOG.info(LOG_DECORATOR);
        LOG.info(" FIN DEL PROCESO ");
        LOG.info(LOG_DECORATOR);
    }

}
```

}

and this is my workspace

[click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUOwq.png)

I know it's in this interface:

[click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2Xk5.png)

but what is the correct variable?
I appreciate any help

To access this menu you can:
*Right click on the launcher
*run As
*run configurations
*Arguments

Comment: Can you use the full path? That would be the easiest. Otherwise you'll want to use the relative path from the directory where the jar is.

Comment: Why not just use Spring Boot?

Comment: How can i do it?

Comment: I need pass this root in the Command Line Arguments "C:\workspaceSIK84\SIK\src-recursos\batch\batchContext.xml" that is the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it, in the interface the default path in my case is "src-recursos", (this is the name for my java version since it's an old project in other versions will be src / main / java)

And I can put as arguments:

"/batch/batchContext.xml" as is with quotation marks

And that works perfect, thanks for taking the time